# Allow user to open file in Windows file system only if they can see the file in an SSRS report

Tags: windows, reporting-services

We have a repository with two parts:

```
File System: holds documents (PDFs) in folders divided by date added.
 SQL Server: holds metadata and the path of each document. (User permissions
             would be based on the metadata held here).
```

The file system is presently locked down so nobody has access.  We are hoping to grant users access to files via a SSRS report.  The report would query the database and return a list of only the documents that the user should have access to.

**How would we grant permissions to the user only for the files retreived by the report?**

Thank you!

Comment: I think the only way you can do this is by using the same AD users and group but this would not stop the users from accessing the file system directly. Don't think you can get SSRS to influence the local file system permissions

Comment: I guess any workarounds would be acceptable as well.  Would my best bet be to set up a web service and link to to that? (pass the file name to the service and have it use windows auth/the database to determine if the user should have permission then have it return the file as a MIME object?)

Answer (score 0):

I think SSRS in this is a red herring. It sounds like what you really want is how to secure the file system based on the results of a SQL query. (SSRS doesn't really have any functionality that will help with this.)

Implementing this through a custom web interface is certainly possible and sounds like a good answer if the using a browser for file access is acceptable. Give the service account permissions to access all the files and then return only the files appropriate for the connecting user. ( Sounds like a straight forward development project. If the requirements are simple enough, then this could be completed in a few days. Of course, make sure you use secure coding practices, since security matters in this application. )